# Jenkins in Docker-Machine

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I created a Docker machine using, 
https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/machine/get-started/#use-machine-to-run-docker-containers

[image]

I have also created a jenkins image on that docker-machine and added the docker-build-step plugin. When I use the Test Connection I get the following message:
[image]

How do I connect my jenkins image to the docker daemon?

Answer (score 0):

The protocol to connect the API is not `tcp` is `http` is a REST API URL what Jenkins expect. Try with:

```
http://172.21.245.40:2376
```